How can I find out the default color of Icons (and other objects) in flutter?
I am new to colors in flutter. I have set up a MaterialApp  with
MaterialApp(
 title: 'Title',
 theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.brown),
  useMaterial3: true,
 ),
 home: const MyHomePage(),
);

When I create an icon without specifying the color attribute, it has by default a brownish color as expected. I would expect that this color is part of the Theme.of(context).colorScheme, where several colors can be accessed.
Where/how can I look up, which of these colors is used by default by the Icon (or other widgets)? For instance, in case I need to use exactly the same color for another design element.

Most of the time they're available in the API docs (doc comments), or sometimes you have to look up on the source code.

They're in the flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart file - if you can see them through all the conditional statements.
